# Check Password in ContentType Controller

Tags: strapi

I want a user to enter his password again if he wants to edit some important data, i. e. after he is already logged in.
How can I check his password in the Controller of a ContentType?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I would like a method like `checkPassword(pwd){...}`:

```
var queryEdit.description = ctx.request.body.description;
var pwd = ctx.request.body.password;

delete ctx.request.body.password;

if (checkPassword(pwd) === true) {
  let obj = await strapi.services.key.edit(ctx.params, queryEdit);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more information about the technical stack?

Comment: @AlexandreNourissier Thanks for the quick reply, I just added something to it.

Comment: Alexandre he is using Strapi, hence his question directly related to that stack.

Comment: Hello! Because it's possible but tooooo long to explain, here is a short video for you https://www.loom.com/share/990d3f842ded4a879b27c0e77c5ac340

Comment: @JimLAURIE Woaw, thanks for the cool explanatory video! Learned again! 
Best regards and a nice Sunday! :)