# How Can i Implements 2FA(using OTP) in Strapi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

Is it Possible to Implements 2FA In Strapi? if yes then I want to Implements 2FA In My Strapi CMS How can I Do Anyone helps me.

I'm trying with that with lots of time.

But it's not working partially.

For frontend override it's work, but backend it does not work.

Exactly  I Want to modify our admin `/auth/local` routes in https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-admin/config/routes.json.

I want to add one extra check for recatch validation  for `handler: "Auth.callback"` in  https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-admin/controllers/Auth.js

Comment: Hello! Do you want to add it for your Users or for the admin panel?

Comment: Hi @JimLAURIE I want to add as an admin panel.

Comment: Hello @JimLAURIE please check with my new description

Comment: @HirenGhodasara are you the same person as OP?

Comment: No @jack, he is my team member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add this feature in your admin panel, you will have to customize it.

To do so, you will have to use the customization concept

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html

The `Admin extension` is the part you will have to use.

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/master/packages/strapi-admin/admin/src/containers/AuthPage

After that, I suggest you add a new endpoint that will send a validate your code.
You will have to check route and controller documentation.

This is really similar to this question:

[Check Password in ContentType Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127410/check-password-in-contenttype-controller)

Here is a video that could help you:

https://www.loom.com/share/990d3f842ded4a879b27c0e77c5ac340

Comment: Until the following issue: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4838 is worked on you won't be able to extend the Admin controllers using the normal override methods, you will need to fork the `strapi-admin` package until it is made a plugin.